# How do I find out if an external drive is in active use (being read/written to)?

Tags: power-management, external-hdd, disk

I have some external drives connected to a power outlet. The outlet is USB switchable, i.e. I can run a program on my PC that physically disconnects the external drives from the power grid. I only use those drives every once in a while for backup. Often I forget to turn them off (though it is really easy with that switchable outlet).

Now what I want to do, is check if they are actively in use. That is, **I want to know if larger amounts of data have been written or read from them in, say, the last half hour** or so. How would I go about such a task?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the best I could do so far was to install [sysstat](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sysstat)  [image: Install sysstat]   and then query the following command every once in a while (replace `sdX` with the name of the drive - you can figure this out by first running `iostat -m` to identify the drive you want):

```
iostat -m | grep sdX | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 5-
```

When these two values (read and write) change significantly, the disk is in active use (not generated by a daemon or something).

I suppose one could do it without installing the bloat of another package by just looking at `/proc/diskstats`. If anyone has a better, more elegant solution, i'd be happy to here it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want you want to list the USB devices (To see if they're in use), you can open a terminal and type `lsusb`.

It might come up with this: (Please note, my output is different to yours)

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2005 Dell Computer Corp. RT7D50 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:3016 Dell Computer Corp. Optical 5-Button Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:a007 Hewlett-Packard
```

It will list the devices, so you can see if they're physically in use.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I think you didn't read the full question.

Comment: Ahh... well, the title's been answered!!! Sorry...